# Private key only wallet for Bitcoin Core regtest

Tags: bitcoind, private-key, regtest, vanity-address

I'm running a private regtest network on GCP. I generated a list of 2000 vanity testnet addresses ordered sequentially from prefixes `mooo1` to `n2ooo` with their respective pub/priv key pairs, and to prevent complications, I want to only have one private key for each node (change in outgoing transactions are sent to the original address). Because there's no security concern in my setting (it's just a performance test, no money or attacker is involved), I want to make each bitcoind instance only use a single private key for all transactions, and not generate new addresses through an HD wallet. This is because viewing transactions is much more streamlined. I can tell which node is sending bitcoins to which other node, and diagnose issues more easily. Is there an option in bitcoind to only use a single private key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bitcoin Core v18 and later, it is possible to create a blank wallet with no keys in it. You can then import the single key you wish to use. It can be imported as a descriptor (with `importdescriptors`), via the `importprivkey` RPC, or via the `importmulti` RPC.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such option.

You can do what you want with the raw transaction RPC interface (`createrawtransaction`, `fundrawtransaction`, `signrawtransaction`, `sendrawtransaction`), though.